# Angular / Typescript - Could not update outside variable in the subscribe function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, frontend

below is my code, I just want to query the backend if email already registered or not, however, no matter what email I pass to the verifyEmail function, the "registered" variable always false, how can I update the registered variable according to the backend response ? Thanks

```
export class MyClass {

   registered: boolean = false;
   message: string = ''

   verifyEmail(email) { 
        this.registered= false
        
        let verifyEmailUrl = "/backend/GetUserByEmail";
        this.http.post(verifyEmailUrl, {
            email: email
        }).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                if (data["user"]) { // can find a user
                    this.message = 'This email has already been registered'
                    this.registered= true
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `if` statement in your `subscribe` block is being executed?

Comment: console.log(data);...what does this look like?

Comment: @HarleyThomas Yes, if statement works, and data return correctly, I just can not update the registered variable outside the subscribe block. tks

Comment: could you upload the entire .ts code?

Comment: @CaiJiaJun - do you mean the view isn't updating? If so, it's because you need to call `detectChanges`. It's not updating "outside" the subscribe func because it's `async` and you're probably checking to see if it's updated synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an arrow function, your scope should be shared and `this.registered` should be updated appropriately. Please provide a `console.log` of data or more relevant code. The issue does not appear to be identifiable from your question.

Answer (score 0):

How do you check registered value? You can't get this value immediately after verifyEmail execution, because value will update some time later. You can create BehaviorSubject then subscribe on it and get register value anywhere when it will update

```
export class MyClass {

   registered$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
   message: string = ''

   verifyEmail(email) {             
        let verifyEmailUrl = "/backend/GetUserByEmail";
        this.http.post(verifyEmailUrl, {
            email: email
        }).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                if (data["user"]) { // can find a user
                    this.message = 'This email has already been registered'
                    this.registered$.next(true)
                } else {
                    this.registered$.next(false)
                }

            });
}
```

In outer code:

```
myClassObject.registered$.asObservable().subscribe(registered => console.log(registered));
```